# Meaning of 身分をわきまえず

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs

Context: a martial arts master is talking (offensively, I think) about one of his students:

> たばこを栽培する山から降りて来たサルですよ。うちの武術学校にスカウトされたからと**身分をわきまえず**李【り】と組んで演武を狂わす厄介者なんです。

What is the meaning of 身分をわきまえず? I found on Kenkyusha dictionary the following example:

> 身分をわきまえる know one's place

but I don't think it fits the context. Maybe here it simply means "without discriminating him for his social position"? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4srch.jpg) you can see the whole page. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「うちの武術学校{ぶじゅつがっこう}にスカウトされたからと**身分{みぶん}をわきまえず**​李
>   {り}​と組{く}んで演武{えんぶ}を狂{くる}わす厄介者{やっかいもの}なんです。」

To use punctuations for you, which manga will never do:

> 「うちの武術学校にスカウトされたからと、**身分をわきまえず**​（、）李​と組んで演武を狂わす厄介者なんです。」

「身分をわきまえ**ず​**」＝「身分をわきまえ**ないで**」

The part of your question that worries me the most is where you said:

> "Maybe here it simply means "without discriminating him for his social position"? "

which suggests that you are not reading the grammar of this sentence properly.

The person who does the 「身分をわきまえ**ず**」 is the "new monkey guy" himself.  It is not something another person is doing to him.  Are you following me?  No one is discriminating against someone else here.

「身分をわきまえ**ず**」, in this context, means "***not knowing his limits***", "***overreaching himself***", etc.  In other words, the definition that you found in the dictionary is valid -- "not knowing one's place".  「ず」 is negative if anyone is unfamiliar with it.

My own quick TL:

> "Just because he was scouted by our martial arts school, he is a nuisanse who overreaches himself by teaming up with Lee and ends up disturbing the performances."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now that you told me that the subject is the monkey guy himself, I am confused by that 狙わす, why is it in the causative form?
Also, could you explain if 身分をわきまえる can ever mean "to discriminate someone for his social position"? Thank you!

Comment: @Marco It's not 狙わす but 狂わす ("to make things go wrong" → "to mess up"). 身分をわきまえる never has such a meaning.